# Making a list of xyz values into a 3d array

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting

I have a list of x y and z values (one x,y and z value per line). These correspond to the length, width and height of a box. I want to find the average height for every 10 by 10 cm square making up this box. This would be easy if the values where in a 3d-array format. but the lines of x y and z are not ordered. Does anyone know a smart way of doing this?

Comment: Please clarify: If x, y and z are not ordered, how are you determining which is which? Are they prefixed by "x: ", "y: "... or do you have another way of distinguishing between them?

Comment: the x y and z are distinguished from each other. There are three numbers on each row. The first is an x, the second is a y, and the third a z. But the rows are not ordered in any particular order.

Comment: Ah, I see. Why do you need each row to be in a particular order? Can't you just loop through the rows and keep track of the height values?

Comment: I feel that would be a very brute force way of doing it. Like to check if both the y and x are within the range i want and then remember the heights. I would have to loop through my list 1700^2. Doesnt seem ideal.

Answer (score 1):

If you're only wanting to do this once, you can just loop through all the points once;

```
sum, n = 0, 0
with open("xyzFile") as f:
  for line in f:
    x,y,z = [int(element) for element in line.split()]
    if x == 10 and y == 10:
      sum += z
      n += 1
```

If you want to do it multiple times, for different values of `x`, `y`, and `z`, then it's a trade off between speed, and memory usage.

You can use the least amount of memory by repeatedly looping through all of the values - that's storing no extra data. On the other hand, you can loop through it once to begin with, and store all the elements in the list which have particular `x`, `y`, or `z` values. For example;

```
xs, ys, zs = {}, {}, {}
cuboids = []
with open("xyzFile") as f:
  for i, line in enumerate(f):
    x,y,z = [int(element) for element in line.pslit()]
    cuboids.append([x,y,z])
    for e, es in zip([x,y,z], [xy,ys,zs]):
      if e in es:
        es[e].append(i)
      else:
        es[e] = [i]
```

and then, you can get a set of all of the `x`, `y`, or `z` lengths by doing something like `xs.keys()`.

Then, if you want to get all of the cuboids which have an `x` length of `10`, then you can do `xs[10]`. If you want to get all of the cuboids with both `x == y == 10` , then you can use `sets` to get all the entries in common;

```
set(xs[10]) & set(ys[10])
```

so then you can calculate the average like so:

```
sum, n = 0, 0
for i in set(xs[10]) & set(ys[10]):
  sum += cuboids[i][2] #z is the second entry
  n+=1
sum /= float(n) #float important to prevent integer maths.
```

disclaimer: i haven't tested any of this!